# Angular Universal Microsoft Edge and Document Injection Problem

Tags: angular, html, typescript, microsoft-edge, angular-universal

We have a page scroll component as shared one. We are using document.scrollHeight in order to adjust where it needs to jump. It perfectly works when using it in Chrome and Firefox(decent versions). But it does not work on Microsoft Edge Browser.

```
import { Component, Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser, DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

        export class PageScrollerComponent {
          constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object,
                      @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any) {  
                if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) { 
                       console.log(this.document);
                       this.scrollto(this.document,400);
                      }
                scrollTo(el, lineNum){
                      el.scroll(0, lineNum)
                }
            }
```

for some reason, in Microsoft Edge, it says document is undefined. It prints to console

> undefined

also. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: I test [this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DWKS.png) on my side in Edge, but can't reproduce your problem. The output like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FXUb.png). So, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'll do it asap. thanks for your reply though...